# How to make a scoreboard where the results are calculated in another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am making an app for a local card game for three players, where there are two activities. One, which is kind of a calculator which calculates the results, and second, where the mentioned results are  (to be) displayed. However, as I am not expert with java and programming in general, it is not working.

What now happens in my app is that the result of player one (Tom in my case), is taken from the calculator activity and displayed in the first `textView` und Player One's name. But when I repeat this operation, with the intent of displaying the second result in the second `textView`, it just overwrites the first `textView`. I have already tried the following:

1. using `startActivity`
2. using `startActivityForResult`
3. finishing the calculator activity (called MainActivity) with `finish()`
4. using `Bundle` instead of `Intent`, but
   none of these did work though.

In the calculator activity (called MainActivity):

```
final Button zapsat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        zapsat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final TextView tomVysledek = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_tom2);
                //final TextView tataVysledek = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_tom3);
                //final TextView kubaVysledek = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_tom4);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("tomVysledek", tomVysledek.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

In `onCreate` of the Results activity (where I want to display the results):

```
TextView textView_tomV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_tomV1);
TextView textView_tomV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_tomV2);
.
.
.
TextView textView_tomV5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_tomV5);

int tomZapis = 0;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        try {
            tomZapis = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("tomVysledek"));

        } catch (Exception e){}
        String tomZapis_tv = Integer.toString(tomZapis);

        if (textView_tomV1.getText().equals("0")) {
            textView_tomV1.setText(tomZapis_tv);
        } else if (textView_tomV2.getText().equals("0")){
            textView_tomV2.setText(tomZapis_tv);
        } else if (textView_tomV3.getText().equals("0")){
            textView_tomV3.setText(tomZapis_tv);
        } else if (textView_tomV4.getText().equals("0")) {
            textView_tomV4.setText(tomZapis_tv);
        } else if (textView_tomV5.getText().equals("0")) {
            textView_tomV5.setText(tomZapis_tv);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Results.this, "Už není místo :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intentres = new Intent(Results.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intentres, 1);
            }
        });
```

As I said, it always displays the result in the first `textView` (`textView_tomV1`), instead of finding the first empty `textView` and filling it with the variable. I believe that is because the `startActivity` actually restarts the activity, but I am not sure about that, and even if it was the case, I wouldn't know what to do with it, either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will solve your problem but when you write this

```
        else if (textView_tomV2.getText().equals("0"))
```

you compare "Editable" with a String...
You  should add toString() like so

```
textView_tomV2.getText().toString().equals("0")
```

and it will compare Strings

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help.